# How to link plurals

Tags: android, android-resources

We have a single app, but with 2 flavors (cats, dogs). And we have a single main resource file for translators:

```xml
<string name="app_name_dog">DogApp</string>
<string name="app_name_cat">CatApp</string>
<plurals name="items_dog">
  <item quantity="one">%d dog</item>
  <item quantity="other">%d dogs</item>
</plurals>
<plurals name="items_cat">
  <item quantity="one">%d cat</item>
  <item quantity="other">%d cats</item>
</plurals>
```

And then, we have our flavored string files, which should just link the correct strings, so we can easily use them in layouts (which are shared across flavors).

So for example, for our cat app we have this:

```xml
<string name="app_name" translatable="false">@string/app_name_cat</string>
```

For simple strings, it's easy. But how can we do that linking for plurals?

Answer (score 0):

Main file

```
<string name="items_dog_one">%d dog</string>
<string name="items_dog_other">%d dogs</string>
```

Flavor file

```
<plurals name="items">
    <item quantity="one">@string/items_dog_one</item>
    <item quantity="other">@string/items_dog_other</item>
</plurals>
```